# Binary search tree with two conditions

Tags: c

I have a classic binary search tree, if cond < 0 addleft else addright. But some of my entries are "flagged" and I want them to be prioritized over "non-flagged" so that when I access the tree it first gives "flagged" entries in an ascending order and then the "non-flaged." Currently I have what I call a "tree root" where I check if the entry is "flagged" and send it to the appropriate tree. It works, but I would rather get rid of it and merge the "flagged" and "non-flagged" trees if possible. How would I go about it?

Comment: Use two trees. A flagged and normal tree. (which is what adding the additional condition would essentially do)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, as I read the question, that's what they have now, and they're trying to move away from it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, keep the essentially two trees. There isn't really an easy way to incorporate additional conditions without changing how a tree works.

Answer (score 2):

You could regard your tree as a BST with respect to a different comparison operator. Something like the following:

```
int compare(/* type */ a, /* type */ b) {
  if (a->is_flagged && !b->is_flagged) return -1;
  else if (!a->is_flagged && b->is_flagged) return 1;
  else return a->value < b->value;
}
```

This essentially does a lexicographical ordering. It regards all flagged elements as less than every non-flagged element, and only considers the value if the flagged status is the same for both items.

Comment: This was how I first attempted to tackle the problem, before settling for two distinct trees. This method has a problem with handling the first entry for some reason; it ends up in a weird place depending on whether it was "flagged" or not, and trying to circumvent the issue resulted in some of the ugliest code I could ever imagine.